# jQuery - checkout process trigger click

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

I'm working with Ecwid and Wix. On the checkout process they don't make it easy to have the Billing address cleared by default. The system automatically takes the shipping address and uses it as the billing address. The website is a cake delivery and the majority of the time, need to have the billing address fields open by default. The URL changes as you go through the checkout process. Once you get to payment the URL updates to /online-store/checkout/payment. The checkout step before that, the URL is /online-store/checkout/delivery.

The parent divs that wrap these sections change dynamically as well. If you haven't completed the payment process the div is: .ec-cart__step.ec-cart-step.ec-cart-step--payment.ec-cart-step--empty, and then updates to .ec-cart__step.ec-cart-step.ec-cart-step--payment.ec-cart-step--current and then once done gets .ec-cart__step.ec-cart-step.ec-cart-step--payment.ec-cart-step--done (this happens on all of the "steps"). By default the billing address displays with a title: **Billing address is the same as Delivery Address** and then has an a tag with a class of *ec-link* you can click to update the billing address. (the text for that link reads "use other address"). I'm trying to use jQuery to trigger clicking that "use other address" but can't seem to get to it. I know I'm doing something wrong but am not sure how to trigger that and was hoping I could create an event listener to look for the parent div class of .ec-cart__step.ec-cart-step.ec-cart-step--payment.ec-cart-step--current. Everything I'm trying is just not working and was wondering if anyone has any advice? :)

I tried putting code within the header not sure if it would need to go in the footer.

I appreciate your time. Please let me know if you have any questions or need more information.

I've tried this code to fire when the shipping method "continue" button is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".ec-cart-step--delivery button.form-control__button").click(function(){ 
$('a.ec-link')[0].click();});
</script>
```

Looking at the code, when you click USE DIFFERENT ADDRESS (and the shipping address is already being displayed as the billing address in a p tag) a form appears once that is clicked.

Comment: Also tried this code:
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("payment") > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.ec-cart-step--payment .ec-cart-step__section:nth-child(3) a.ec-link').trigger('click');
    }, 5000);
  }
});
</script>`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to accomplish a different goal, but running in to similar problems with the ecwid cart